# Qt Including Files in Different Directories

Tags: c++, qt, inclusion

So I've read a few posts and articles about how to go about doing this and one option was to do:

```
#include "../file/file.h"
```

But when I use this method, it still cannot find the file. The other way was to add the root of the project to the include path.

So here is an example directory:

```
main_dir
   - dir2
      -dir3
        -header.h
   -dir4
      -dir 5
        -source.cpp
```

So if I am trying to include header.h from source.cpp, how do I do this?

My .pro file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-02-17T12:52:00
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = project1
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    dir4/dir 5/source.cpp \

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    dir2/dir3/header.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: Many operating systems would consider `.../file/file.h` to be a malformed path.  Did you mean `../../file/file.h`?

Comment: Well, I meant ../file/file.h. I put an extra period, but I was essentially restating what I found from other threads and articles.

Comment: My version is `#include "dir2/dir3/header.h"`. Paths should be relative to a folder that contains `.pro` file (no mater where the `*.cpp` file is)

Comment: @Drop I also read that. When I begin to use it in Qt Creator, Qt Creator recognizes it and shows me what files I can use when I attempt the inclusion. However, when I begin to build it, it says that the file does not exist and then stops.

Comment: Then show us your `.pro` file. Does `dir2/dir3/header.h` physically exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve the problem.

1. Use `#include "../../dir2/dir3/header.h"` in `source.cpp`.
2. If you can add `main_dir` to the list of include directories, (`-I<main_dir_path>`), then you can use `#include "dir2/dir3/header.h"` in `source.cpp`.
3. If you can add the toplevel directories under `main_dir` -- `main_dir/dir2` and `main_dir/dir4` -- to the list of include directories, then you an use `#include "dir3/header.h"` in `source.cpp`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But how do I do this in Qt Creator?

Comment: @UioShi, I am not familiar with Qt Creator. Can't help you there.

Comment: @UioShi Add this line to you `.pro` file to add an include path: `INCLUDEPATH += <main_dir_path>`. This causes QMake (used by Qt Creator) to set everything correctly. So you do not need to manually add the `-I` parameter.